# Failed at the @ production script. Error running npm run production

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am facing issue while using the following command

```
npm run production
```

after execute following command i see following error

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors
error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at preparePluginsArray (E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\svgo\lib\svgo\config.js:64:20)
    at module.exports (E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\svgo\lib\svgo\config.js:32:28)
    at new module.exports (E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\svgo\lib\svgo.js:21:19)
    at E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\postcss-svgo\dist\index.js:95:16
    at Object.creator [as postcssSvgo] (E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\postcss-svgo\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:150:35)
    at E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\cssnano\dist\index.js:295:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\cssnano\dist\index.js:282:29
    at creator (E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\cssnano\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js:150:35)
    at processCss (E:\wamp\www\smm.yasmalik.com\node_modules\css-loader\lib\processCss.js:199:16)
```

Comment: Can you display your ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss fille?

Comment: here is my app.scss file 
`// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.navbar-laravel {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}`

Comment: I think everything looks fine in your bootstrap. I guess something was wrong on your `node_modules`

Comment: Then what should i do @ChristianGallarmin if i remove node_modules will loose all packages i have installed manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was issue with my node_modules folder. there were some extra useless packages so simply i just deleted node_modules and install it again with following commands

**Step 1**

Delete *node_modules* manually

**Step 2**
Install the node_modules folder again:

```
npm i
```

**Step 3**
Update existing packages

```
npm update
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some conflicts with versions of some npm packages. 
Try to reinstall npm:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: with this will i loose all existing downloaded packages? i mean i have to add again all npm packages ?